# Can't build CSipSimple

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, csip-simple

I'm trying to build [CSipSimple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/csipsimple/wikis/HowToBuild.wiki)

I get such error:

```
# External sources fetched out from external repos/zip
/Users/Nikita.Leshchev/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/core/build-local.mk:151: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
/Users/Nikita.Leshchev/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/core/build-local.mk:151: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Isources/modules/audio_processing/aecm/include -Isources/modules/audio_processing/aecm/../utility -Isources/modules/audio_processing/aecm/../../.. -Isources/modules/audio_processing/aecm/../../../common_audio/signal_processing/include -Isources/modules/audio_processing/aecm/../../../system_wrappers/interface -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -flax-vector-conversions -S -o sources/modules/audio_processing/aecm/aecm_core_neon_offsets.S sources/modules/audio_processing/aecm/aecm_core_neon_offsets.c
make[1]: Isources/modules/audio_processing/aecm/include: No such file or directory
make[1]: [sources/modules/audio_processing/aecm/aecm_core_neon_offsets.S] Error 1 (ignored)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sources/build/generate_asm_header.py", line 46, in <module>
main(sys.argv[1:])
File "sources/build/generate_asm_header.py", line 30, in main
infile = open(argv[0])
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sources/modules/audio_processing/aecm/aecm_core_neon_offsets.S'
make[1]: *** [sources/modules/audio_processing/aecm/aecm_core_neon_offsets.h] Error 1
make: *** [webrtc-preprocess] Error 2
```

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/csipsimple-dev/t88OgOms_vI/qTzJGrNPazAJ) suggests to check variables and installed soft. But my variables is ok

`echo $PATH` output:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/php5/bin:/Users/Nikita.Leshchev/Downloads/pcre-8.39/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Headers:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/Nikita.Leshchev/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/Nikita.Leshchev/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/Nikita.Leshchev/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/
```

Variables `ANDROID_NDK` and `ANDROID_SDK` defined. All required soft installed

`which ndk-build` output:

```
/Users/Nikita.Leshchev/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle//ndk-build
```

I did everything like in documentation, but i have this error. Can anybody help?

NDK Version 13.11.3345770

SDK Version 25.2.2

OSX 10.11.6

**UPD** I coudn't build it, but i found this [repository](https://github.com/tqcenglish/CSipSimple) I could download and build it without any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, not on 100% for a while, but this error i have resolved.
This and some other files i found in this [repository](https://github.com/CryptoCall/csipsimple/tree/master/jni/webrtc/sources/modules/audio_processing/aecm)

Comment: I coudn't build it, but i found this [repository](https://github.com/tqcenglish/CSipSimple) I could download it and build without any problems